# How to multiple sum mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that sums everything in te field "total" and its ok.

```
$cleaner = $connection->query("SELECT *,SUM(total) as total FROM ventas where fecha='$datenow'");
```

but
I want to create more filters, when the caja is nails

```
$cleanerx = $connection->query("SELECT *,SUM(total) as total FROM ventas where fecha='$datenow' and caja='NAILS'");
```

why is not working, I read the tutorials at php but I don't understand why is not working.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
$cleaner = $connection->query("SELECT *,SUM(total) as total,(SELECT SUM(total) as total FROM ventas where fecha='$datenow' and caja='NAILS') as totalnails FROM ventas where fecha='$datenow'");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: your welcome please accept the answer if its help full to you :)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the inconvenience, we have a problems but i have a caja named "NAILS/SALON" only filtered with the date and the caja ?